# how to deploy maven project changes into Tomcat's web application?

Tags: git, macos, shell, maven, scripting

I have a tomcat running in my mac and I have deployed a war file of my application. So, I am using repository as Git and I have a maven project in it. Remember, I had already deployed a war file. I do have maven project of that application (which means this maven doesn't have war file) now all I want is whenever I do changes in my Git project the changes should be deployed in Tomcat(inside already my application is running). Please excuse me I have zero knowledge in maven.

Please help by providing some suggestions. Is that shell scripts can do anything with this?

Comment: Does maven deploy the war on tomcat? Have you tried [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  If Eclipse the Tomcat Eclipse plugin help with this?

Comment: @mr zaratustra, No maven can build a same kind of war as if the one running in Tomcat which means both are different intances...

Comment: @ Mr Smith, Yes. I am using Eclipse with Egit plug in of Git, moreover I can add the Tomcat in Eclipse but this tomcat has been already deployed with a war.

Comment: Guys, please let me know if I didn't make sense.

Comment: Do you want to deploy your application when you push it to a remote or when you commit something in your local repo?

Comment: Exactly,when I am committing / intends to deploy my changes from my local repo. Hope I have explained what I was trying...

Answer (score 5):

First off all you need to be able to deploy you app on tomcat automatically, here is a [good article](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) Basically you need to make maven run `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. For this you need to add:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/mkyongWebApp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

to your `pom.xml` in the plugins section. Then you can deploy war on tomcat automatically:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

Next step is to create a [post-commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). In the simple way it might look like:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-commit
#!/bin/sh
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

After every commit git will execute this hook that runs this simple command.

Comment: That's Awesome.. Great Thanks